# Concatenating collections in Python

Tags: python, collections, concatenation, python-itertools, flatten

`itertools.chain` is said to convert `chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F`. Yet, I see that

```
>>> Set(itertools.chain([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]))
Set([(4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)])
```

I see that no hierarchy is affected. Similarly, `list(itertools.chain([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))` [is said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/4563974) to have effect on lists. But I see no flattening in my case

```
>>> list(itertools.chain([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 2):

> > What the hell is going on?

You misread the [answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python/953097#953097)

In that answer was this line:

```
merged = list(itertools.chain(*list2d))
```

Note the use of the asterisk (or 'splat') operator.

In your question, there is no such operator:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))  
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

To make sense of the answer you reference, try this:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Which is equivalent to removing the outer-most brackets:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The fist argument is a list of iterables (tuples) not [one iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). You can use `chain.from_iterable()` to flatten your list:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```